# Detect on which element content was entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've few div's which are generated dynamically.

I would like to detect inside which div content was entered and then perform some action on the other div's.

For example -

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example">Some random text</div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

If I have the above 3 div's and I enter in some content inside the 2nd div, I would like to detect inside which example class div the text was entered and then perform some action on the remainder of the div's, say make the border red or enter in some paragraph tags.

How could I do this using javascript or jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean by "enter some content"?

Comment: Please post some JavaScript or jQuery in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the filled `div`s and then do your action on the result:

```js
$('.example').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === '';
}).text('test');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example">Some random text</div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

The above will assign the text `test` to the empty `div`s only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not()` to eliminate the element that triggered the event.  I'm not sure how your text that triggers the event gets into the div, so I'll give an example using the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.example').on('click', function() {
    $('.example').not(this).each(function() {
      console.log($(this));
      //do something with $(this)
    });
  });

});
```

(You will need to change `'click'` to the appropriate event.)